# Efficiently determine which units are in the range of AOE spells in RPG games, like World of Warcraft and dota 2?

Tags: algorithm, game-engine

As AOE, area of effect, is always a circle, the first thought I came up with was to calculate the distance between each unit in the map to the center of the circle, and to determine a unit is in the range of the circle by the formula (X<sub>unit</sub> - X<sub>center</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (Y<sub>unit</sub> - Y<sub>center</sub>)<sup>2</sup> < R <sup>2</sup> , where R is the radius of the circle.

Apparently, it is not an efficient algorithm. Maybe it can be improved by downsizing the calculating area first, and then use the formula above. But calculations are still time consuming operations, and hashing may be an efficient way to solve this problem while I actually don't know how to do :( . And I REALLY wonder what the algorithms are used in the games.

Comment: You need a spatial index. Checking all units every time is doomed to fail.

Comment: First of all, MMOs (WoW, L2, Aion, Tera, GW, whatever else) typically use 3 coordinates. However, MMOs naturally maintain a _knownlist_ for each player (typically for each character), in order to avoid flooding the player's game client with data about every single unit in the whole game world. Thus, the same _isInsideRadiusSq_ algorithm can be used pretty efficiently, as you only need to check units in the immediate vicinity, which are conveniently stored in the _knownlist_.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better that effects will update some coordinated map, and units will check once they move/every time step which effects are applied to their current coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

These might help:

Collision Detection, Bounding Circle
http://mastrgamr.net/xna/xna-collision-detection-bounding-circle/

Bounding Box Collision Detection 
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180069-xna-2d-bounding-box-collision-detection/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Comment: I think you're right that using a quadtree, or something similar, could speed things up. But isn't a bounding circle essentially what he's already doing? A bounding box would be even less efficient still, I would think.

Comment: Using **quadtree** and increasing **grid density** to approximately deal with the circle area might be a better solution.